# Difference Between Public and Private Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

While wiring up a proof of concept, I am attempting to determine if a public certificate can be used to secure https requests flowing from public facing web servers to an internal/private Application Load Balancer. The certificate would be on the internal ALB. From what I read in [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/#:%7E:text=One%20key%20difference%20is%20that,applications%20to%20trust%20private%20certificates.), I'd expect that a public certificate can be used and would be easier to configure/maintain/deploy.

Do I need a private certificate for an internal/private Application Load Balancer or will a public certificate serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public certificates can only be created and verified for domain names which are publicly accessible.

To issue you a certificate, the certificate authority requires you to present public proof of ownership such as solving a DNS challenge.

If the domain that you want to issue the certificate for is private then you won't be able to issue a public certificate for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it would have to be private then the ALB is using a dns like xxx.com.local